# d3.js Hierarchical Edge Bundling dynamic data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to dynamically update the data on a hierarchical edge bundling chart based on [https://bl.ocks.org/bstitt79](https://bl.ocks.org/bstitt79/66fe8f50dccaac6a58094566d2a870fe).

I create an update function to wrap the behavior of the example above.

```
var links, nodes;      
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")        
var node = svg.selectAll(".node");

function update(root){

    links = packageImports(root.descendants());
    cluster(root);  
    nodes = root.descendants(); 

   link = link        
       .data(links)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
       .attr("class", "link")
       .attr("d", line)           
       .style("stroke", function(d) { 
           var splitName = d.source.data.name.split(".");             
           var group = splitName[0] + '.' + splitName[1];            
           return color(group); 
       });      
       link
            .exit()
            .transition()
            .attr('r', 0)
            .remove();             


    node = node
        .data(nodes.filter(function(n) { return !n.children; }))
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("dy", ".31em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; });

}
```

now let's assume that I have two json sources, (flare1.json, flare2.json) with different data inside.
The default datasource is flare1, after 5000ms I want to change the data to flare2, so I tried with a timeout like this.

```
d3.timeout(function() {            
   root = packageHierarchy(jsonData);            
   update(root); 
}, 5000);
```

But this isn't working as expected, because the result is a chart with all the overlapping data from flare1 **and** flare2.

[First Datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kioh.png)

[Result After 5000ms timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlQAM.png)

What i'm doing wrong? can someone help?